# obtaining elements from a generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Lets suppose I have a simple class Product:

```
class Product{
    private String name;
    //constructor
    //get name method
}
```

and also a class that is actually working with generics in Java:

```
class ListR<t>{
      //more coding here...
      public void print(){
          Node a=first;
          while(curr!=null){
               System.out.println(a.elem); //prints the value of a node
               a=a.next;
      }
}
```

so if I make a list of Products objects in my main program like the following:

```
ListR<Product> list=new ListR<>();
Product p1=new Product("books);
//...
list.add(p1)...
list.print();
```

how can I make so my print method prints the name of the products stored, I have tried to use the generics inside the A class in the print method, but I am not quite sure how to do it. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This compiles? `System.out.println(a.elem);` Object does not have a public field called `elem` as far as I know.

Comment: no, it is only a sample code

Comment: What does `a.elem` do? What does it return?

Comment: it is only a implementation of a linked list, a.elem, returns the element part of a node

Comment: `"no, it is only a sample code"` -- please post code that makes sense. Don't post sort-of kind-of code.

Comment: why do you want to use generics in here, or that class in particular? why not just `class ListR`... actually, you look like you want a print a low level linked list, in which case it can't really be object but a node of the list

Comment: `ListR<Product> list=new List<>();` makes no sense.

Comment: @Kon I guess the `List` there is a typo for `ListR`

Comment: Where's the generic you want to print? Since all Objects have a toString method you can just print a generic `<T> void pg (T g) { System.out.println(g); }`. Then override toString in Product so it returns 'name'. Otherwise can't tell what you want to do exactly. Don't see why you can't just print the name if you have a Product.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, if you keep things like they are now.
As far as `ListR` knows, it contains `Object`s, and `Object`s do not contain any particular information. They have a method `toString`, that you can override, but it's not suggested to use it for presentation purposes.

#### Option 1: Internal interface

What you can do, if you're allowed to change things a bit, is to force the contents of `ListR` to implement an interface, such as

```
public interface Printable {
  String printedForm();
}
```

and then

```
class Product implements Printable{
  //TODO: Whatever you want
  @Override
  public String printedForm() {
    //TODO return a pretty printed form of the product.
    //e.g. return this element's name
  }
}

class ListR<T extends Printable>{
  //...
  public void print(){
    Node a=first;
    while(curr!=null){
      //You can now invoke printedForm, because you forced T to implement Printable
      System.out.println(a.printedForm());
      a=a.next;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Option 2: external formatter

If you don't want / can't change the implementation of Product, or if you want to implement a more flexible style of printing, you can use an external `Formatter` object, that will format your products.

```
//Unmodified
class Product { }

interface ObjectFormatter<T> {
  String stringForm(T obj);
}

class ProductFormatter implements ObjectFormatter<Product> {
  @Override
  public String stringForm(Product obj) {
    //TODO return product name or whatever you want
  }
}

class ListR<T> {
  private final ProductFormatter<? super T> fmt;

  public ListR(ProductFormatter<? super T> formatter) {
    this.fmt = formatter;
  }

  //...

  public void print(){
    Node a=first;
    while(curr!=null){
      System.out.println(fmt.stringForm(a.elem));
      a=a.next;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you create the list:

```
ListR<Product> list = new ListR<>(new ProductFormatter());
```

Comment: thanks @Giulio Franco, your answer was great, it is a shame that a lot of people has downvote this question and were not able to put a simple answer by here